# Proving that a (complex) differential form is of type $(p, q)$ iff its conjugate is of type $(q, p)$ using complex vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, complex-geometry, multilinear-algebra, complex-manifolds

Let $(M, J)$ be a $n$-complex manifold and $p+q=k$ where $0\leq k \leq 2n$. I'm looking for a clean way to prove that $\mu\in \mathcal{A}^k(M, \mathbb{C}):=\Gamma\left(\bigwedge^k T_{\mathbb C}^*M \right)$ is a complex diferrential $k$-form of type $(p, q)$ iff $\bar{\mu}$ is of type $(q, p)$. Now, first of all, I want to do everything avoiding real arguments in a coordinate-free fashion using complex vector fields (i.e, smooth sections of the complexified tangent bundle of $M$,  which I will denote by $\mathfrak{X}(M, \mathbb C):=\Gamma\left(T_{\mathbb C}M \right)$).

Ok, so firstly, we define $\bar{\mu}\in \mathcal{A}^k(M, \mathbb{C})$ by
$$(1)\qquad\qquad\qquad
 \bar{\mu}(Z_1,\ldots,Z_k):= \overline{\mu(\bar{Z_1},\ldots,\bar{Z_k})},\qquad\qquad  Z_1,\ldots,Z_k\in \mathfrak{X}(M, \mathbb C).$$
I'm aware that one can check that [a $k$-form is a $(p,q)$-form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195248/when-is-a-k-form-a-p-q-form) when $\lambda\star \mu= \lambda^p \bar{\lambda}^q \mu$, with $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ (or more generally, for $\lambda \in \mathcal{C}^\infty(M, \mathbb C)$) and where $\lambda\star \mu\in \mathcal{A}^k(M, \mathbb{C}) $ is defined as
$$(2)\qquad\qquad\qquad\lambda\star \mu (Z_1,\ldots,Z_k):= \mu(\lambda Z_1,\ldots, \lambda Z_k).$$

Now, the trouble comes here. If we want to check (2) applied to (1), we end up obtaining that $\lambda\star \bar\mu=\lambda^p\bar{\lambda}^q \bar\mu$, which is definitely NOT what we want. However, if we instead define $\bar \mu$ by
$$(3)\qquad\qquad\qquad
 \bar{\mu}(Z_1,\ldots,Z_k):= \overline{\mu(Z_1,\ldots,Z_k)},$$
then we arrive at the desired conclusion.

Now, in fact I've taken definition $(3)$ for granted for some time, but now I'm convinced it is NOT the right one.
If we play with a toy example, let's say $ \mu = dz\wedge d\bar{z}$ and $Z=a\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}+b\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}, W=\alpha\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}+\beta\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}$, we all agree that $\bar\mu= d\bar{z}\wedge dz$, and we can easily check that $\bar\mu(Z, W)=\overline{\mu(\bar Z, \bar W)}=b\alpha-a\beta$, whereas $\overline{\mu(Z, W)}=\overline{a\beta - b \alpha}$, so definition $(1)$ is the right one.

So, what am I missing here? I'm certain that the conjugate is given by $(1)$. Not many authors bother to explain what $\bar\mu$ actually is, or how to compute it, a small portion of them just say that if $\mu=\alpha+i \beta$, then $\bar\mu=\alpha -i\beta$ (which I agree with, but it is quite dry). In fact, formula $(1)$ appears in Poor's Differential Geometric Structures, a quite venerable and underrated text, and as we saw in the toy example, it is quite the right one.

All that being said, we can infer that maybe $(2)$ doesn't work as expected for complex vector fields. If so, what can we do so that $(2)$ works for my desired proof?
I guess we can just take the following definition for a $(p, q)$-form and everything is settled:

*A complex $k$-form is of type $(p, q)$ if and only if it vanishes whenever applied
to $p+1$ vectors of type $(1, 0)$ or to $q + 1$ vectors of type $(0, 1)$.*

The desired conclusion holds trivially using the previous definition, but I'm quite unsatisfied because $(2)$ is a pretty nice way to check if a $k$-form is a $(p, q)$-form. Any help or comments are appreciated. Just to be clear, I don't have trouble with the fact that $\mu$ is a $(p, q)$-form iff $\bar \mu$ is of type $(q, p)$   (for example, using the definition above or local coordinates), rather, I want to see why $(2)$ doesn't hold or what does it need to work correctly in the fashion I want to use it.

Comment: This is a continuing source of confusion in complex geometry, which has been addressed here numerous times. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885191/definition-of-dz-i-otimes-d-barz-j-frac-partial-partial-z-m-c-frac-part/2885936#2885936), for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically a question on linear algebra. Let $V$ be a finite dimensional real vector space and let $\mu \in \Lambda^k(V_{\mathbb{C}}^{*})$. There are two ways to think about $\mu$:

1. The first is as an alternating **real** multi-linear map $\mu \colon V \times \dots \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Note that the input of $\mu$ are "real" vectors in $V$ and the output is a complex number. This corresponds to thinking of $\mu$ as an element of $\left( \Lambda^k_{\mathbb{R}}(V^{*}) \right)_{\mathbb{C}} = \Lambda^k_{\mathbb{R}}(V^{*}) \otimes \mathbb{C}$.
2. The second is an alternating **complex** multi-linear map $\hat{\mu} \colon V_{\mathbb{C}} \times \dots \times V_{\mathbb{C}} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Here the inputs are complexified vectors and the output is a complex number. The complex structure of $V_{\mathbb{C}}$ comes from the complexification (and not from $J$!). This corresponds to thinking of $\mu$ as an element of $\Lambda^k_{\mathbb{C}}(V_{\mathbb{C}}^{*})$.

Both ways of thinking about $\mu$ are equivalent and useful. The relation between $\mu$ and $\hat{\mu}$ is given by "extending $\mathbb{C}$-linearly". Namely, for example, for $k = 1$,
$$ \hat{\mu} \left( v + iw \right) = \mu(v) + i\mu(w). \label{eq:single} $$

---

So let's think about $\mu$ as in $(1)$. The vector space $V$ has no natural conjugation but $\mathbb{C}$ does so we can define
$$ (1) \qquad\qquad \overline{\mu} \left( v_1, \dots, v_k \right) = \overline{ \mu \left( v_1, \dots, v_k \right)}. $$
This is another real multi-linear map so everything is well-defined.

Now let's think about $\hat{\mu}$ as in $(2)$. In this case, both $V_{\mathbb{C}}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ carry natural conjugations and if we want $\overline{\hat{\mu}}$ to be $\mathbb{C}$-linear, we are forced to use them both and define
$$ (2) \qquad\qquad \overline{\hat{\mu}} \left( v_1, \dots, v_k \right) = \overline{ \hat{\mu} \left( \overline{v_1}, \dots, \overline{v_k} \right)}. $$
This is indeed a $\mathbb{C}$ multi-linear map. Under the isomorphism $\mu \mapsto \hat{\mu}$, the "single conjugation" $\overline{\mu}$ corresponds to the "double conjugation" $\overline{\hat{\mu}}$.

The bottom line is that whenever you work with real vectors, you use $(1)$ and whenever you work with complexified vectors, you use $(2)$. If the vectors in $(2)$ are real, then clearly the inner conjugation does nothing.

---

Finally, let's introduce a complex structure $J$ on $V$. It seems you have misunderstood the $(p,q)$ criteria. In order to check whether $\mu$ (thought of as in $(1)$ above) is a $(p,q)$ form, you define for $\lambda = a + ib \in \mathbb{C}$
$$ (3) \qquad\qquad \lambda \star \mu (v_1,\ldots,v_k):= \mu \left( av_1 + bJv_1,\ldots, av_k + bJv_k \right) $$
and then check whether $\lambda \star \mu = \lambda^p \overline{\lambda}^q \mu$.
In order to check whether $\hat{\mu}$ (thought of as $(2)$ above) is a $(p,q)$ form, you define
$$ (4) \qquad\qquad \lambda \star \hat{\mu} (v_1,\ldots,v_k):= \mu \left( av_1 + b\hat{J}v_1,\ldots, av_k + b\hat{J}v_k \right) $$
where $v_1,\dots,v_k$ are complexified vectors and $\hat{J}$ is the $\mathbb{C}$-linear **extension** of $J$ to $V_{\mathbb{C}}$ and then check whether $\lambda \star \mu = \lambda^p \overline{\lambda}^q \mu$. Note that this is **not the same** as
$$ \hat{\mu} \left( \lambda v_1, \dots, \lambda v_k \right) = \lambda^k \hat{\mu} \left( v_1, \dots, v_k \right) $$
(as $\hat{\mu}$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear).

Finally, if you use $(2)$ and $(4)$, you see that if $\hat{\mu}$ is a $(p,q)$ form then
$$ \left( \lambda \star \overline{\hat{\mu}} \right) \left( v_1, \dots, v_k \right) = \overline{ \hat{\mu} \left( \overline{av_1 + b\hat{J}v_1}, \dots, \overline{av_k + b\hat{J}v_k} \right)} = 
\overline{ \hat{\mu} \left( a\overline{v_1} + b\hat{J}\overline{v_1}, \dots, a\overline{v_k} + b\hat{J}\overline{v_k} \right)} = \overline{ \lambda^p \overline{\lambda}^q} \overline{\hat{\mu}} (v_1, \dots, v_k) = \lambda^q \overline{\lambda}^p \overline{\hat{\mu}} (v_1, \dots, v_k)$$
and so indeed $\hat{\mu}$ is a $(q,p)$-form.

Comment: What a great explanation, everything is clear now, you just saved me a lot of headaches and a great deal of related stuff is crystal clear now. This is the kind of subtle things that book authors should explain carefully or at least left as an exercise with all the ingredients in the table.

Comment: @EternalBlood: You're welcome! I also share your sentiment, it seems that most of the sources for complex geometry are "eager" to get to the "interesting stuff" and expect the reader to implicitly understand all the relevant linear algebra so it's rare to find a detailed discussion of these issues.

Comment: @EternalBlood: BTW, my calculation used the fact that $\hat{J}$ (which is usually denoted just by $J$) satisfies $\hat{J}(\overline{v}) = \overline{\hat{J}(v)}$. This follows from the fact that $\hat{J}$ is the complexification of an operator and so it commutes with the real structures.